# Teen Book with Two Boys Transported to Future

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I am searching for a book I read as a young boy (1980's to early '90s). I don't really recall many key facts other than I think it was either one boy or two brothers, from possibly war time, being transported to the future where they attend a school. At lunch they scan their wrists to pay, and the time projects on their wrist. One of them had a taste for a dessert that, when you peeled the lid back, turned into a spoon to eat it with.

Comment: [A Tale of Time City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Time_City)?

Comment: @sq33G - You're right. That's exactly what he's described. I've credited you in my answer.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/197340/book-in-which-children-escaping-london-get-sent-to-an-alternate-reality (which is newer but has an accepted answer)

Answer (score 2):

Per sq33G's earlier comment, the book you're describing is almost certainly "[A Tale of Time City](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Tale_of_Time_City)" by Diane Wynne Jones;

[image: "A Tale of Time City"]

### Pots that have lids that turn into spoons;

> *The pots, Vivian found, were sort of stuck to the air. She had to give
>   a little pull to get them loose. She discovered that you peeled back
>   the lid, and if you needed a spoon or a fork, the lid shrivelled itself
>   into a spoon or fork shape. Algae soup was not at all pleasant, like
>   salty pond water*

### Paying by scanning their wrists

> *“I’m paying,” said Jonathan, and recited a string of numbers. “Yes, but are you in credit?” said the waitress. “Show.” Jonathan pressed
>   one of the buttons on his belt and held his hand out with a row of
>   signs shining on his palm. The waitress looked, nodded, and pressed
>   buttons on the pink matching belt round her pajamas*

There's a complete (and I assume copyright friendly) version available online [here](http://dcc.vu/Media/E-Books/Diana%20Wynn%20Jones/Diana%20Wynne%20Jones%20-%20A%20Tale%20of%20Time%20City.pdf).